# Dynamically insert angularJS contextMenu on HTML tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, contextmenu

I am using this [angularJS contextMenu](https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu) module on my application and I need to insert this inside some HTML tags dynamically. I am trying something like this but it isn't working.

```
e.client.html("<a context-menu=\"menuOptions\">click here</a>");
```

I have `menuOptions`declared on my scope like this:

```
$scope.menuOptions = [
    {
        text: 'Object-Select',
        click: function ($itemScope, $event, modelValue, text, $li) {
            $scope.selected = $itemScope.item.name;
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Object-Remove',
        click: function ($itemScope, $event, modelValue, text, $li) {
            $scope.items.splice($itemScope.$index, 1);
        }
    }
];
```

Someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need angular to compile your dynamic context menu, so it can handle the `context-menu` directive. The best way doing this is:

```
//define the Html to insert in a variable:
var dynContextMenu = "<a context-menu=\"menuOptions\">click here</a>";

//append to content
e.client.html(dynContextMenu);

//then compile it
$compile(dynContextMenu)($scope);
```

I hope this helps.